# Qual a melhor forma de criar uma aplicação mobile que se comunique com um Webserver?

Tags: php, android, web-service

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo *mobile* que deverá conter o mesmo conteúdo do site, e é necessário que o mesmo banco de dados (*MySQL*) utilizado pelo site seja também utilizado pela aplicação mobile.

Acredito que criar uma conexão direta do aplicativo *mobile* (*Android*) para o banco de dados remoto seria uma falha de segurança, pois qualquer um poderia abrir o *apk* e descobrir os dados de conexão, portanto seria necessário criar um *Webservice* exclusivamente para esta transferência de dados, mas também em meu conceito teria o mesmo defeito: segurança, pois qualquer um poderia acessa-lo e enviar ou receber informações.

Qual sua a melhor técnica para transferir dados entre um *Webservice* e uma aplicação *mobile* sendo que este *webservice* precisa estar "fechado" a acessos externos e não autenticados.

Comment: Qual a linguagem do código do serviço no servidor?

Comment: PHP - Laravel 5.1

Comment: Pesquise sobre Cordova Phonegap, a curva de aprendizado é menor e pode ser usado javascript.

Comment: @RBoschini, acredito que você compreendeu errado, não estou perguntando como desenvolver uma aplicação mobile, mas sim como criar um webservice para prover uma comunicação entre a aplicação e o banco de dados de força segura e autenticada.

Comment: Desculpe amigo, entendi errado mesmo. Mas sobre consumir webservice com seguranca, eu faria metodo digest de autenticacao e meu ws respondendo em json. O server fornece um token e vc pode consumir os dados enquanto esse token estiver valido, igual API do facebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A partir do momento que você precisa criar um webservice/API para acesso de clientes mobile, o seu webservice se torna público. E webservices públicos sempre serão sujeitos a acesso não autorizado uma vez que para que seu aplicativo precisa necessariamente conter as informações para conseguir acessá-lo.

Contudo existem técnicas para que seus dados de acesso fiquem menos vulneráveis. A mais comum é a utilização de Proguard para obfuscar o seu código em caso de engenharia reversa. SSL para evitar mitm e sniffers e criptografias mais avançadas como autenticação por HMAC.

Mas nenhuma dela é 100% a prova de hackers.

Comment: Mas como funciona por exemplo aplicações mobile como o Skype, ou Netflix, que é necessária uma comunicação direta com os servidores e bancos de dados? esta conexão é aberta de forma que qualquer um pode acessar, ou somente a aplicação em questão que consegue?

Comment: Não se faz comunicação com servidores sem ser por API ou Webservices. Justamente para o caso em que alguém consigo acesso, não vai conseguir fazer mais do que os métodos que estão definidos nesta API. Desse modo seu banco de dados fica (se certa forma) protegido. Sem contar que empresas como Skype e Netflix tem uma equipe de engenheiros de segurança que monitoram cada acesso aos seus servidores e estão prontos para bloquear qualquer acesso suspeito.

Answer (score 1):

**HTTPS** (Hyper Text Transfer Protocol Secure - protocolo de transferência de hipertexto seguro) é uma implementação do protocolo HTTP sobre uma camada adicional de segurança que utiliza o protocolo SSL/TLS. Essa camada adicional permite que os dados sejam transmitidos por meio de uma conexão criptografada e que se verifique a autenticidade do servidor e do cliente por meio de certificados digitais.

Fonte: [wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)